# Ruby on rails - Inserir um render dentro de uma tag html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como faço para adicionar um render dentro de uma tag HTML?

Por exemplo, isso aqui funciona **ok**:

```
<%= render :partial => "feed/new_card", :locals => {
      :main_image => image_tag('feed/new_badge.jpg')
    } %>
```

`<div><%= main_image %></div>`

Porem gostaria de fazer algo assim:

```
<%= render :partial => "feed/new_card", :locals => {
      :main_image => <%= render feed/new_album %>
    } %>
```

`<div><%= main_image %></div>`

é possível? Pq desse jeito esta dando erro aqui =/

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

No seu controller:

```
@main_image = render_to_string(partial: 'feed/new_album')
```

Na sua view:

```
<%= render :partial => "feed/new_card", :locals => {
  :main_image => @main_image.html_safe
} %>
```

Mas tome cuidado render_to_string é mais pesado do que render, se isso for muito usado pode causar lentidão.
Explique um pouco melhor o que voce está tentando fazer, pois esse código que você mostrou para mim não faz muito sentido e deve haver uma forma mais eficaz de resolver o seu problema.